# Self-hosted CMS for code snippets

Tags: software-development, cms, self-hosted, source-code

I'm looking for a self-hosted code snippets tool like Gist but a little more powerful.

Would be great if it could have some (or all) of the following features:

- user management
- categories
- syntax highlighting
- a lot of supported languages

Comment: User management like wikipedia has user management?

Comment: Did you ever find something? I would like this too

Answer (score 1):

[Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/) has, in addition to being a git repository manager, a snippet section.

It has user management and syntax highlighting for a lot of languages.

There are no categories, labels or tags for snippets at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of self-hosted snippet tools / managers:

- https://github.com/nicksergeant/snipt

  - Offers nearly all the features. However, *it's not clear if it is still maintained*.
  - (**teams** / tags / syntax highlighting / diff. languages)
- https://github.com/claudehohl/Stikked

  - (encryption / diffs / syntax highlighting / diff. languages)
- https://github.com/seejohnrun/haste-server

  - (syntax highlighting)
- https://github.com/codervault/codervault

  - (syntax highlighting / diff. languages)
- https://github.com/cespare/pastedown

  - (syntax highlighting / diff. languages)
- https://glot.io

  - (user management / syntax highlighting / diff. languages / **execute code**)
- https://privatebin.info/

  - (encryption / syntax highlighting / diff. languages)
- https://github.com/bartTC/dpaste

  - (syntax highlighting / diff. languages)

#### WordPress plugins

- https://github.com/mAAdhaTTah/wp-gistpen

  - (?user management? / ?categories? / syntax highlighting / diff. languages)